# How to Clear cache files for .less

Tags: magento2.3, cache, styles, shell

I'm in Production mode. I like to change some styles in my website, so i edited .less

for example:

```
app/design/frontend/Templatemonster/theme/web/css/styles-l.less
```

I used "flush Magento cache" from backend and run

```
 setup:static-content:deploy
```

still my modified files not updated. What can I use to solve this problem?

Comment: Firstly check do you have your changes in generated files if not then change it developer mode and rm the generated files in pub/stati then deploy it and I guess it will work from now

Comment: After changed to developer mode i used setup:upgrade, then only it's work fine.

Comment: Answer to your question and accept it @mohana

Comment: But can we use "setup:upgrade" at any time?

Answer (score 2):

**you should never edit files on your prod-system! you should fix your deployment process if you have to do that!**

you need to delete all files in var/view_preprocessed and run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` to recompile the less.